# Reactstrap modals all open on button click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactstrap

I'm having trouble with the `reactstrap` modals. I'm looping through an array and it makes modals and buttons, and gets information in a nice card.

Now when I click on a button to open the modal, all modals open even if I didn't click the button on the card. All (39) open. I was hoping you all could help me out <3

Modal State

```
this.state= {
modal:false,
}
```

Toggle Function

```
toggle(){
this.setState(prevState =>({
  modal: !prevState.modal
}));
}
```

Everything that gets returned

```
     return (
      <div key={item.ID}>
      <ul>
        <Modal isOpen={this.state.modal} toggle={this.modal} id={item.ID}>
          <ModalHeader id={item.ID} toggle={this.toggle}>{item.Naam}</ModalHeader>
          <ModalBody>fdass</ModalBody>
          <ModalFooter><Button onClick={this.toggle} color='primary'>fddss</Button></ModalFooter>
        </Modal>

        <Card style={{ width: '18rem' }}>
        {/* <CardImg src={"http://static.floraxchange.nl/artikelen/"+ item.Fotos.ID +"_v_t8.jpg"} alt={item.Naam} /> */}
          <Card.Body>
            <Card.Title>{item.Naam}</Card.Title>
            <Card.Text>
              Hoogte: {item.Hoogte}<br />
              Potmaat: {item.Potmaat} <br/>
              ID: {item.ID}
            </Card.Text>
            <Button color="danger" data-target={'#' + item.ID} onClick={this.toggle}>More information</Button>
          </Card.Body>
        </Card>
      </ul>
      </div>
    )
```

Comment: Where are your other modals ?

Comment: @Treycos The return gets repeated, so the modal you see is the one that gets looped.